# Parse number in XSL with a thousands seperator

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to parse a number from an input XML file. The problem I have is that this number contains a grouping seperator. For example:

**10,250.75**

When I try to parse this using the number function I get **NaN** as the result.
Is there any way to pass a format to the number function? I've found a lot of information regarding **outputting** a number in a different format, but not much for reading formatted input.

Example showing the problem:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number('10,250.75')" />
```

Gives the rseult:

```
NaN
```

Note - I am using XSLT version 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(translate('10,250.75', ',', ''))" />
```

Comment: Thanks - this solves the problem. It feels a bit hacky... but if there's no other way I'll accept this as the answer!

Comment: I don't see this as a "hack". There is a more generic solution that would filter out all characters except digits, the minus sign and the decimal dot - but I believe it would be overkill in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your help - good point, this is a good fix for this particular issue.